# how to get an array from controller to ajax function in laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

Hey there i'am using laravel 4 and i'am still beginner in all this.
what i want to do is to get an array of data from my controller to my ajax function for helping me drawing my chart

here is my controller function

```html
 public function getAPI()


        $stats = DB::table('reponse')
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
            ->remember(1440) 
            ->get([
                DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
                DB::raw('etatSatisfaction as value')
            ]);

        return $stats;
    }
```

and this is my view i want to replace the static data with the data from my array

```html
<script >
var chartData1 = [];


generateChartData();

function generateChartData() {
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 500);
  firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

    var a1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + i)) + 100 + i;
    var b1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 + i)) + 500 + i * 2;


    chartData1.push({
      date: newDate,
      value: a1,
      volume: b1
    });
  
  }
}

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  type: "stock",
    "theme": "none",

  dataSets: [{
      title: "first data set",
      fieldMappings: [{
        fromField: "value",
        toField: "value"
      }, {
        fromField: "volume",
        toField: "volume"
      }],
      dataProvider: chartData1,
      categoryField: "date"
    },

    
  ],

  panels: [{

      showCategoryAxis: false,
      title: "Value",
      percentHeight: 70,

      stockGraphs: [{
        id: "g1",

        valueField: "value",
        comparable: true,
        compareField: "value",
        balloonText: "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
        compareGraphBalloonText: "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>"
      }],

      stockLegend: {
        periodValueTextComparing: "[[percents.value.close]]%",
        periodValueTextRegular: "[[value.close]]"
      }
    },

    {
      title: "Volume",
      percentHeight: 30,
      stockGraphs: [{
        valueField: "volume",
        type: "column",
        showBalloon: false,
        fillAlphas: 1
      }],


      stockLegend: {
        periodValueTextRegular: "[[value.close]]"
      }
    }
  ],

  chartScrollbarSettings: {
    graph: "g1"
  },

  chartCursorSettings: {
    valueBalloonsEnabled: true,
        fullWidth:true,
        cursorAlpha:0.1
  },

  periodSelector: {
    position: "left",
    periods: [{
      period: "MM",
      selected: true,
      count: 1,
      label: "1 month"
    }, {
      period: "YYYY",
      count: 1,
      label: "1 year"
    }, {
      period: "YTD",
      label: "YTD"
    }, {
      period: "MAX",
      label: "MAX"
    }]
  },

  dataSetSelector: {
    position: "left"
  }
});

chart.addListener('rendered', function (event) {
    var dataProvider = chart.dataSets[0].dataProvider;
  $( ".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      minDate: dataProvider[0].date,
      maxDate: dataProvider[dataProvider.length-1].date,
      onClose: function() {
          $( ".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField" ).trigger('blur');
      }
  });
});


</script>

    @stop
```

Can anyone help please

Comment: where exactly are you doing the AJAX call?

Comment: normally it will be in my view replacing this  var chartData1 = [];


generateChartData();

function generateChartData() {
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 500);
  firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

    var a1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + i)) + 100 + i;
    var b1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 + i)) + 500 + i * 2;


    chartData1.push({
      date: newDate,
      value: a1,
      volume: b1
    });
  
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already defined your controller function,now you need to specify the route for this action.

> A **route** -in brief- is the way the requests made by the browsers
>   get to communicate with the methods of the controllers.

In the routes.php file *(In Laravel 5 you can find it in App\Http\routes.php)*

you could a create new route. Check [Laravel Routing Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#basic-routing)

```
Route::post('/FunctionAPI', 'MyController@getAPI');
```

Then in your JS file you could create a method like this

```
public function getData()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type :"POST",
        url: "/FunctionAPI":
        success:function(data)
        {
            for(var index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
            {
                //Clean the array in case you need to
                charData1 = [];

                chartData1.push({
                  date: data[index].date,
                  value: data[index].value,
                  volume: data[index].volume
                });         
            }
        }
    })
}
```

the **data** parameter in the success function is what your getAPI function would return.

**NOTE**

You should know the format in which your data is coming, that way you could know how you're going to populate your chart. (In case you don't know)

**UPDATE**

In order to populate your chart, I'll asume your data is retrieving this way:

```
[
    {
       date: "2014-04-04",
       value: "Some Value",
       volume: "Some Volume"
    },
    {
       date: "2014-04-04",
       value: "Some Value",
       volume: "Some Volume"
    },
    {
       date: "2014-04-04",
       value: "Some Value",
       volume: "Some Volume"
    },
    {
       date: "2014-04-04",
       value: "Some Value",
       volume: "Some Volume"
    }    
]
```

Comment: you are sending data to controller here, i want to get data from controller to my JS and push it in my table

Comment: No. This example is receiving data from the controller

Comment: So can you tell me please how i can push this data in the var chartData1 = []; just like they did with the static data in the example above?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ggderas, i appreciate